# Groovy Grails send/receive variable

Tags: javascript, json, grails, groovy

Don't understand some groovy grails details.
I have controller LogsController, and i have logs.gsp and everything mapped, so when i try to get /logs/applog - getting logs.gsp or some data from render.
So the question is: how can I return a variable? I want to do something like that:
opening page (logs/applog) -> closure returns (renders?) variable as JSON -> page logs.gsp gets that variable, parse it with javascript and show data.
But if I write

```
render var as JSON;
```

getting just JSON and don't see page logs.gsp
How i can do this?
Thanks.

Comment: it's not *sending* anything anywhere >)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render(view: 'logs', model: [var: var])` will send variable `var` from controller to logs.gsp. In gsp file, you can access by using ${var}. All of this will be done in server side so you don't need JSONObject.

In your case, If you want to get JSON variable and use javascript to access it:

- In gsp file you need a ajax request
- In controller, [check ajax
  request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665067/identifying-ajax-request-or-browser-request-in-grails-controller). If it's is ajax request, do `render var as JSON` to return JSON Object to client. If not, do `render(view: 'logs', model: [var: var])` to return a page as normal.

Comment: but not model=[var: var], only model: [var: var]
Thanks!